# jQuery dataFilter response undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am fetching data from an external api via jsonp with jQuery.ajax().

this is my ajax setup:

```
var ajax_options = {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    url: url,
    data: parameters,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); // works, prints the correct data
    },
    dataFilter: function (response, type) {
        console.log(response); // prints undefined
        console.log(type); //prints "jsonp"
    }
};
$.ajax(ajax_options);
```

I want to use the dataFilter function to preprocess my response for error handling. But the response argument of this function is always undefined. In the success function however, I get the correct response data.

Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Converters mentioned below but the jQuery ajax page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ says: "Some types of Ajax requests, such as JSONP and cross-domain GET requests, do not use XHR; in those cases the XMLHttpRequest and textStatus parameters passed to the callback are undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify that this issue is a pain in the arse. What needs to be done is to use $.ajaxSetup({}); along with the converters:

**$.ajaxSetup**

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Then, you'll need to use Converters to handle your dataType, dataFilters, callbacks, and parsing.

**jQuery.Extensions - Converters**

> http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Converters

While you don't *have* to use Converters via $.ajaxSetup -

```
$.ajax({ converters: 'params go here' });
```

Because of the scenario you're facing, all data that is passed as your jsonp needs to have this converter applied to it. This should provide you with a more realistic control based on your expected result type and needs.