# json parser error on mobile network

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, mobile

I am having a hard time resolving an issue. When my app is on wifi the ajax calls work perfectly. When I turn off wifi and use the mobile network I get a JSON Parser Error. here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://**MYDOMAIN**.net/ios/leaders.php",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert(msg);
})
.error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert(xhr.statusText);
  alert(xhr.responseText);
  alert(xhr.status);
  alert(thrownError);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
})
```

Comment: What is the response when connected to mobile network?

Comment: It says Json Parsererror

Comment: I'll rephrase my question. What is the response of ajax request from server? You can try using `dataFilter()` for printing raw response.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but how would I implement dataFilter()?

Comment: Take reference from the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478428/jquery-datafilter-response-undefined

Comment: unfortunately dataFilter is not working either. here is the full message I get from the .error function

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error:
Unable to parse JSON string

Comment: Also, this apparently is only happening on AT&T's mobile network